# SQL Server : Replace (Charindex)

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I have a SQL Server table with numbers in column `no`:

```
12345670000115 
14245670000116 
58492010000118
```

I need a function that will remove one number `1` from right side of number, so result must be like:

```
1234567000015 
1424567000016 
5849201000018
```

I find some solutions to use `charindex()` with `substring()`, but my SQL skills are poor so I really need help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Are you wanting to remove the next to last character in these values? Is it only when that character is a 1? And what is the datatype for this mystery column?

Comment: OP. There are several people taking wild stabs at a solution to your question. Any chance you can provide us with some details so we know what the actual question is??

Comment: I don't try much because of my poor sql.. My first step is: select left(barcode, 11)  +''+ right(barcode,2) as barcodeOk from test

Comment: Can you explain the actual logic you need. Help us understand what you are trying to do and the code is incredibly simple. As it is we are guessing your requirements which is incredibly difficult.

Comment: If `no` field is digit (int, bigint, smallint etc.) than use `(no-100)`, if its text (varchar, nvarchar etc) then `select  no, LEFT(t.no,CHARINDEX ('1',t.no ,len(t.no)-3)-1)+ RIGHT(t.no,2) as result
from (VALUES ('12345670000115'),
('14245670000116'),
('58492010000118' ),
('145670000120')) as t(no)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is varchar data here is an easy way to accomplish this. BTW, I would suggest you not use column names like 'no'. It is a reserved word and it is horribly ambiguous. Does that mean number or the opposite of yes? If it is number as I assume it would be better to name the column with an indication of what the number is. PartNumber, ItemNumber, CatalogNumber whatever...

```
LEFT(no, len(no) - 2) + RIGHT(no, 1)
```

Comment: But I think it won't work in case when No = 12345670000120

Comment: At this point it is hard to say which approach will work since the OP has not been very clear in the details.

Comment: Of cource, but as we can see there are records with numbers 115, 116, 118 and I think 120

Comment: Not in the sample data posted. Only 115, 116 and 118.

Comment: Column name is not "no", it's "barcode", I give it name "no" just in question :) It's varcha(20).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
declare @charToReplace char = '1'
select REVERSE(stuff(REVERSE(no), charindex(@charToReplace, REVERSE(no)), 1, ''))
from table
```

or

```
  declare @charToReplace char = '1'
  declare @tmp_table TABLE (NO varchar(16))
  insert into @tmp_table
  select REVERSE(NO)
  from yourtable

  select REVERSE(stuff(NO, charindex(@charToReplace, NO), 1, ''))
```

Comment: This works but REVERSE is not very efficient. And you could use the literal 1 instead of getting the length of a hardcoded string. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, I've fixed it. What do you think about create a temp table and fill it with reverced string and then use query with only one reverse? It will be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular data, if the numbers fit a BIGINT, one easy way is to treat them like numbers:

**Setup**

```
create table #tmp (
    number VARCHAR(16)
)

insert into #tmp values ('12345670000115'), ('14245670000116'), ('58492010000118')
GO
```

**Script:**

```
select number, cast( (cast(number AS bigint) - 100) / 100 * 10 + cast(number AS bigint) % 100 as VARCHAR(16))
from  #tmp
GO
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my example. If I have number 12345670000115 result with your script is 12345670000015. It just change 1(third character from the rear) with 0, it must remove it. Please help, thanks :)

Comment: @Bloger - I think I got it right this time, but it is far from being very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve problem. There is answer in which I remove one character 1 and update whole table. Thanks all for help!

```
Update myTableName 
set barcode=substring(barcode,1,11)+substring(barcode,13,1) 
where len(barcode)>= 14
```